# Tab size in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr, antlr4

How can I set the tab (`'\t'`) size in ANTLR4? In ANTLR2 for instance there was the `tabSize` property.

```
JavaLexer lex = (JavaLexer)lexer;
lex.setTabSize(1);
```

Comment: Have not seen that property in Antlr3 or 4.  Did it just affect formatting in the generated source files?

Comment: No, it just sets the number of whitespaces corresponding to a tab. It is a feature from AnTLR2.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted something similar to show (in a graphical user interface) the location of a lexical error.  I used an override on the lexer to report the StartIndex of the error, and then used that StartIndex to place the cursor at the location of the error.  It handles tabs correctly in my testing, because it counts from the beginning of the input stream:

```
public class BailLexer : LISBASICLexer
{
    public BailLexer(ICharStream input) : base(input)
    {
    }

    public override void Recover(LexerNoViableAltException e)
    {
        string message = string.Format("lex error at position {0} ", e.StartIndex);
        BasicEnvironment.SyntaxError = message;
        BasicEnvironment.ErrorStartIndex = e.StartIndex;  // save off value here for use later...
        throw new ParseCanceledException(BasicEnvironment.SyntaxError);
    }

}
```